# Android firebase can't see project in firebase console

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-console

I have connected my app to Firebase by using android studio (tools/Firebase ...) and created a new Firebase project, but it did not appear in the Firebase console, I have followed the exact same steps I did see in a video and in the video a new Firebase project was created in the Firebase console. I do see the project in https://console.developers.google.com/cloud-resource-manager, but it just won't appear in the Firebase console, why?

Comment: Did you tried here : https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/   maybe it happends because you are with another gmail account

Comment: yes I did, and I made sure the account is correct.

Comment: maybe there is a limit, I already had some projects I made for iOS, is there any limit?

Comment: its weird because it dosnt let you create new projects if you have the limit complete

Answer (score 3):

I went to google-services.json file in the app directory from Project view in Android Studio and if you select the url "firebase_url" and put it in a browser, you can access without problem.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem.

What I found in my case:
Few days back, I was deleting some unnecessary projects from Google Developer Console, (not from "firebase console") and I deleted this project by mistake. 
My good luck, it was not too delaied, not deleted permanently.

Solution: Restore the project through Google Developer Console, from Pending Deletion list. https://console.developers.google.com/cloud-resource-manager?pendingDeletion=true

Comment: it was a bug from Google, I wrote them and they fixed for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you have any previous project then click one of them in [console.firebase.google.com](https://console.firebase.google.com)
If you don't have any project then simply create a new one.
You will see the project introduction page like [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09VLd.png) Click the arrow denoted circle area. Now here you can see all the projects including the project you created in the firebase assistant in android studio. You will see the project in "Other projects"

Comment: you should attach the image to answer

Comment: I have attached the image like a link. Click the hyperlinked "this image" to see the image. I don't know how to display the image in the answer directly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a "good-to-know" thing for people that stumble upon this.. I had a plugin that allows the user to enable CORS everywhere by altering http responses, when this is activated my firebase projects wouldn't load

- CORS Everywhere (Firefox)

[image: CORS Everywhere]

- Allow CORS: Access-Control-Allow-Origin

[image: Allow CORS: Access-Control-Allow-Origin]